# Configure .htaccess to work on a PHP Framework (Silex)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silex

I have a working path on my Apache2 localhost (linux):

```
http://localhost/lab/silex/web/index.php/hello/name
```

I want to become:

```
http://localhost/lab/silex/hello/name
```

Now I have Rewrite mode enabled and tested.

I have placed my .htaccess file in my silex/web folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I still cannot see the clean url working.

Comment: Try putting the `.htaccess` file in `/lab/silex/` and use `FallbackResource /lab/silex/web/index.php`. Although proper virtual hosts, even on your local machine, would have my preference. You might become more inclined to not adhere to best practices for live environments if you don't consistently follow them on local environments too.

Answer (score 10):

in your main folder try this: (for you this would be the silex folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and in the web folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: if i try and navigate to an image then it gets passed to the index to work out the route, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/lab/silex/web/index\.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lab/silex/web/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. 

Alternatively I tried as well: `FallbackResource /index.php`, since I have Apache 2.2.22

Comment: Are you getting 404 for `http://localhost/lab/silex/hello/name`? Also are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, I am getting 404 Not Found. No, there are no more rules.

Comment: Is there any other .htaccess anywhere in your system being used by silex framework?

Comment: No. there aren't. Strange.

Comment: Hmm that is really strange. Then are you sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled & working?

Comment: Yes, When I run sudo a2enmod rewrite, the feedback is: Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: OK first make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Please see my answer. I don't know the code above didn't worked. Can you figure out why? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only problem is that the link works only for: http://localhost/silex/web/hello/, I want to remove that /web part

Comment: ok check updated answer now. This .htaccess needs to be in `/lab/silex/`

Comment: Strange it doesn't work like you mention. Nor if I move it to web folder and change the base path to /lab/silex/web

Comment: As I said first you need to make sure this .htaccess is even being read. See my comment above with 500 check. Do that test in `/lab/silex/.htaccess`

Comment: If I add garbage text, I encounter `500 Internal Server Error`. 

Does it mean it reads the htaccess or not? Moreover the line `^(.+)$ web/index.php/$1 [L]` is causing the same 500 server error.

Comment: Also If you are getting 500 for the suggested rule (make sure you have RewriteCond also) then check your Apache error.log

Comment: It maybe needs a virtual host created in order to work. 

That is strange since as it is the website only run with the /web/ url piece handcrafterd in the browser address bar.

Comment: ok one more edit, make sure this is in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file

Comment: Apache logs are not concludent. Not sure I understood your last comment. If I place the .htaccess in lab/silex in the form it is below it gives me 404 error.

Comment: not in lab/silex. Latest `.htaccess` should be directly in `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, directory where `lab/ is subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that works, but still only for /silex/web/hello/name. I want to make it work for /silex/hello/name

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why don't you just move your index.php in the root directory and replace the require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php' by require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php' ?
Do you really need the web subfolder with Silex ?