# htaccess: Using silex/symfony and web-directory redirect

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, symfony1, silex

I'd like to use silex with a "web"-directory for public files.
The structure will look like:

```
-project
--vendor
----silex
----...
--web
----index.php
--.htaccess
```

So I'd like to have a .htaccess script that does this tasks:

- If I request a file ./myInstallationPath/file.php it should check if the file exist inside ./myInstallationPath/web/ and if so, redirect to it internal
  . Otherwise it should internal redirect to ./myInstallationPath/web/index.php
- If I request ./myInstallationPath/web/ it should remove the "web/" from the URL so that the user will not see the "web"-directory. Then the point above should be used.

Because the path of the project can be root, but also a sub-folder, the installation path could determinded the following way:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=INSTALLATION_ROUTE:%1]
```

This is my existing code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:INSTALLATION_ROUTE}web/$1 !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:INSTALLATION_ROUTE}web/$1 !-d [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %{ENV:INSTALLATION_ROUTE}web/index.php [L]
```

It'll check if the file does not exist inside web/ and if so, it will redirect to index.php How must the other rules look like, to meet the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Apache Virtual Hosts. My project structure looks like yours. I use this in http.conf for creating the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
   ServerAdmin localhost
   DocumentRoot "c:/apachefolder/htdocs/"
   ServerName localhost
   ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost:80>    
   DocumentRoot "C:/apachefolder/htdocs/mysilexproject/web"
   ServerName myproject.dev
   ServerAlias myproject.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I added first the localhost one to still being able to access other sites like before using VirtualHosts.

Once you have created the VHost, you will have to set the dummy domain you have used for you project in you system host file.

In case of Windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

`/etc/hosts` for most linux distros

After this I put in the `web` directory of my project my `.htaccess` file that looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Finally restart your apache to get the config changes applied. Now you will be able to access your site using `http://myproject.dev`

Comment: It's a good idea if you have access to the http.conf, but I don't have access to it neither to change the document root

Comment: then I think this might be usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/20605956/3682741